# how to compare the distance and duration strings returned by google directions api

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Since the directions google map api returns the drivind distance and time between origin and destinations. Now If I have to compare the time and distance value in java ,how can we do it. 
eg : Distance1= 22km     Distance2= .98km
     Time1= 1hour 2 min  Time2 =  3 min

Now if I have to compare the time and distance string which is greater ,how we can do it?

Comment: What you have tried just add your research and code here.

Comment: Fot eg: When we query this 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?sensor=true&origin=sector+38A%2CNoida&destination=28.5328810,77.2747850
the out put is this
Duration:22 mins
Sector 20, Noida

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this incorrectly. This is related to Javascript not Java. They are 'not' the same language.

As for your question. You can retrieve the values from the directions by accessing the json directly.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(response['routes'][0]));
```

That line put straight after your OK check should help get you started.

Comment: Yes, i know this..but i am using xml to retrieve the output. I have already fetch the values for duration values in a string. Now suppose if I want to compare those strings.. how will I do it. For eg: 
String time1="2 hours 24 mins";
String time2="12 mins";

Comment: What are you comparing them to?

Comment: I am comparing both time values.. which is greater or smaller so that we can proceed with the resultant

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert those values to numbers, e.g. kilometers for the distance and minutes for the times - e.g. 22 and 0.98, resp. 62 and 3 for your examples. Then you can simply compare the numbers.

I don't know if the api returns the values always in kilometers and hours/minutes, you should make sure of that, and then "simply" parse the values you get. For the distances this would be something like so:

```
double distance1 = Double.valueOf("22km".replace("km,""));
double distance2 = Double.valueOf(".98km".replace("km,""));
if (distance1 < distance2) {
    System.out.println("distance1 is smaller");
} else if (distance2 < distance1) {
   System.out.println("distance2 is smaller");
} else {
   System.put.println("both distances are the same.");
}
```

For the time parts, the parsing will be a bit more complicated.

And yes, I know you can do this much more elegant using regular expressions but I'd have had to try around to get them right, so I went with the simple way.